# Where does SharePoint 2016 store templates including custom ones

Tags: 2016, feature, site-template, web-template

Trying to create a new site based on template using following method:

```
SPWeb.Webs.Add(parameters here);
```

But getting following error:

```
The site template requires that the Feature {9c4b5df2-2fd3-75f9-526c-c6d3f01f8745} be activated in the site collection.
```

Is there a way to find this feature based on GUID? This was migrated from another server which is no longer available but its C drive is intact.

I checked that it is reading templates from this code:

```
SPSite.GetWebTemplates(1033);
```

Does it read templates from `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE`

Because if yes then I can look for that missing template or whatever is that in C drive of old server. Don't know how to find what this feature exactly is and where to find this template.